# ConstraintValidatorContext not sending messages

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, bean-validation

I have a custom constraint that is working.

I want to send an error code to be resolved from my message bundle.

When I do this:

```
context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{customConstraint.duplicateName}")
        .addConstraintViolation();
```

The property is read and the correct text is displayed.

When I try this:

```
context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{customConstraint.duplicateName}")
        .addPropertyNode(null).inIterable().atKey(field)
        .addPropertyNode("name")
        .addConstraintViolation();
```

the correct node is resolved but the message is ignored and a property code of
'`CustomConstraint.mapName[field].name`' is returned.

I have a gradle dependency of '`org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final`'

Can some one please tell me why the message is being ignored when I define the node path?

**EDIT**

Here is the constraint defintion:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy=CustomConstraintImpl.class)
public @interface CustomConstraint{

String message() default "{CustomConstraint.mapName}";

Class<?>[] groups() default {};

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
```

}

and here is part of the implementation class:

```
public class CustomConstraintImpl implements ConstraintValidator<CustomConstraint, Map<String, Object>> {

@Override
public void initialize(CustomConstraint c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Map<String, Object> map, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
...
...
in this method is where the above context code is being called
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit? It would for example help to see where and how you use your custom constraint. I am also not sure what exactly you mean with "property code of 'CustomConstraint.mapName[field].name' is returned.". The message is not resolved at all? Is it just '{customConstraint.duplicateName}' or yet something else?

Comment: Hardy - The constraint is used on a Map<String, Object>.  It is very odd, the message is not resolved at all.  I would think to see '{customConstraint.duplicateName}' unresolved but it totally ignores it and creates a message code based on the path and adding the class name of the constraint first.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I'd create an issue here https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HV and see what happens.

Comment: Anything? did you create the bug?

Comment: Sorry no.  I was on vacation for a week.  Will try and submit a bug today.  I was trying different implementations yesterday.  Method level, class level.  All have the same result.

Comment: Created issue with hibernate : https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-986

Comment: thanks to @Hardy I was able to get this example working.  There must have been a typo somewhere in my code since the only difference was that the implementation and interface were defined in the same source file.